# Why is there no hide/show column event for the Kendo Grid for Angular

Tags: angular, events, event-handling, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid for Angular in my Angular application. We've enabled the columnMenu feature that allows you to hide/show columns from a popup:

[image]

I'm surprised to find that the ColumnMenu documentation lists no events that fire when a column is hidden/shown:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/menu/

So I'm wondering if there is a way to hook a handler to the showing or hiding of columns in response to hitting the "apply" button on the column menu (or just a handler for the column menu apply button itself).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was also surprised.

Here is a quick workaround :

```
   `(columnVisibilityChange)="onVisibilityChange()"`
```

You can add this on your HTML grid definition and catch it.